# Are reduced SVD and truncated SVD the same thing?

Tags: svd

Truncated SVD: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html

Reduced SVD, I thought this is essentially the same thing, and it appears to be actually more commonly called this way.

If you could provide reference, that'll be great.

Comment: People can define things as they wish, but to me the former is still a decomposition of A, just without explicitly including the zero singular values. While the latter would be understood as an approximation to me.

Comment: What do you mean by approximation, I thought reduced SVD is the one without explicitly including the zero singular values, thus called reduced. I am uncertain what truncated means yet.

Comment: @Ian, do you agree with my answer, please? Thanks!

Comment: For the record, this video discussed this topic (full SVD vs reduced SVD vs truncated SVD): https://youtu.be/AbB-w77yxD0?t=81.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose the shape of $A$ is $m \times n$, written as $\underset{m \times n}{A}$, with rank $r$.

In **full SVD**:

- $U$ is composed of $r$ orthonormal columns that span the column space of $A$ and $m - r$ orthonormal columns that span the left null space of $A$.
- $\Sigma$ is diagonal and composed of the square root of eigenvalues of $A^T A$ (or $A A^T$) padded with zero rows and columns to be of shape $m \times n$.  The diagonal elements are also called the singular values of $A$.
- $V$ is composed of $r$ orthonormal columns that span the row space of $A$ and $n - r$ orthonormal columns that span the null space of $A$.

\begin{align}
\underset{m\times n}{A}  &= \underset{m \times m,}{U} \underset{m \times n,}{\Sigma} \underset{n \times n}{V^{T}}
\end{align}

In **reduced SVD**:

- the $m-r$ columns that span the left null space are removed from $U$.
- the padded rows and columns of zeros are removed from $\Sigma$.
- the $n-r$ columns that span the null space are removed from $V$.

so it becomes

\begin{align}
\underset{m\times n}{A}  &= \underset{m \times r,}{U_r} \underset{r \times r,}{\Sigma_r} \underset{r \times n}{V_r^{T}}
\end{align}

Note, both reduced SVD and full SVD results in the original $A$ with no information loss.

In **truncated SVD**, we take $k$ largest singular values ($0 \lt k \lt r$, thus truncated) and their corresponding left and right singular vectors,

\begin{align}
\underset{m\times n}{A}  &\approx \underset{m \times k,}{U_t} \underset{k \times k,}{\Sigma_t} \underset{k \times n}{V_t^{T}}
\end{align}

$A$ constructed via truncated SVD is an approximation to the original A.

**Example 1**

For $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$, where $m = 2$, $n = 3$, and $r = 1$.

*Full SVD*:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}   & \color{Blue}{- \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & \color{Blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{10}       & \color{Gray}{0} & \color{Gray}{0} \\
\color{Gray}{0} & \color{Gray}{0} & \color{Gray}{0}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \color{Red}{- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & \color{Red}{0} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \color{Red}{  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} & \color{Red}{0}
\\0 & \color{Red}{0} & \color{Red}{1}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}

Note,

- the left null space columns in $U$ are colored blue.
- the padded zero rows and columns in $\Sigma$ are colored gray.
- the null space columns in $V$ are colored red.

*Reduced SVD*

just remove the colored rows and columns, and it ends with reduced SVD.

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}   \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{10} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\\0 
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}

Since A has only one positive singular value, we can't demonstrate truncated SVD with it.

**Example 2**

We use another example $B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ with $m=2$, $n=3$, and $r=2$ to show truncated SVD.

*Full SVD*:

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{3} & 0 & \color{Gray}{0} \\ 
0 & 1 & \color{Gray}{0} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \color{Red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \\ 
\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & 0 & \color{Red}{- \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \color{Red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}

*Reduced SVD:*

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{3} & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\ 
\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & 0  \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}

*Truncated SVD:*

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{3} 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}^T
\end{align*}

Only the largest singular value $\sqrt{3}$ is taken. $\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}$ is an approximation of the original $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: You should not append zeros to U,V. You should extend them to be orthogonal matrices and put zeros in $\Sigma$.

Comment: I've made the correction. Thanks for pointing out, but I wonder why is that useful?

Comment: It's just for theoretical reasons, so that $U,V$ are "bona fide" orthogonal matrices, which is one of the main advantages of the full SVD over the reduced one. Pretty much any real world numerical computation will be on the reduced SVD or a truncated SVD.

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to write $A \approx U \Sigma V^T$, since the truncated SVD is just an approximation and you said that yourself.